# Consume purchase for In-app billing does not work on Android 6

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am testing as an alpha tester. The code that I am using is the latest "Trivial drive" classes from Google and IAP5. I can consume my purchase on an older device that has an older version than Android 6. I test exactly the same code on a device  with Android 6 and I get the error below. Why does this happen?Here is my code and error message:

http://www.mobile-visuals.com/mess.txt

I have to post my code and error message in this link, because Stackoverflow kept saying that it was not properly intented.

Comment: If it andriod 6 You have to ask the permissions of your app from your app. This might be missing so only in lower versions to 6 it is working.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Which permission should I ask for to consume the request?

Comment: The only permission required for in app billing is com.android.vending.BILLING. It is not dangerous, so it should not make a difference for Android 6. Why is consume request not working on Android 6? I believe this has nothing to do with the permissions. The dangerous permissions are listed here:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html Try to give run time permissions. PLease follow up the link.

Comment: I am experienced with runtime permissions and I have already read that info page. I have added runtime permissions to about 10 apps and I know how it works. My question is which runtime permission should I request for In-app billing? The only permission required is com.android.vending.BILLING. It is not dangerous, so there is no need to ask for it with runtime permissions.

Comment: So consumeRequest simply does not work in Android 6? There is no dangerous run time permission to ask for here.

Comment: It is very frustrating that customers keep complaining about this and I can not to do anything about it! Is there a basic problem with Google's "in app payment" solution?

Comment: I am considering to stop  using Google's "in app payment" in new apps if there is no solution to this.